# How to configure Airflow URL in email alert

Tags: airflow

Does anyone know how to configure airflow such that link in the email alert  is not pointing to localhost:

Try 1 out of 2
Exception:
Bash command failed
Log: Link
Host: vm232
Log file: /home/dev/airflow/logs/test_email_alert/email_alert/2017-03-15T20:00:00.log
Mark success: Link

---

Link i got is "localhost"

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

In airflow.cfg, there's a section called **webserver.** Under that you will find a parameter called **base_url.** Configure that for the e-mail.

Comment: Bear in mind this is an URL so you'll need to include the `https://` (or `http://` prefix) or the web server will blow up.